# Looping structure best approach

Tags: python

Consider these two variants of the same loop structure:

```
x = find_number_of_iterations()
for n in range(x):
    # do something in loop
```

and:

```
for n in range(find_number_of_iterations()):
    # do something
```

Will the second loop evaluate the method `find_number_of_iterations` in every subsequent loop run, or will the method `find_number_of_iterations` be evaluated only once even in the second variant?

Comment: You could easily have tested this yourself, but: either way, the function is only called once.

Comment: How can I test this. My mentor has criticized my code which is in the second variant as he says it will evaluate in every loop run

Comment: Then you get to tell your mentor they're wrong! You could test this by passing a function that records how many times it gets called as `find_number_of_iterations`, and checking afterwards whether that's `1` or not.

Comment: You could also use a simple print statement in `find_number_of_iterations` It will only print once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your mentor's confusion is traceable to the fact that the semantics of Python's for loop is so much different than in other languages.

In a language like C a for loop is more or less syntactic sugar for a while loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
i = 0;
while(i < n)
{
    //do stuff
    i++
}
```

In Python it is different. Its for loops are iterator-based. The iterator object is initialized just once and then consumed in subsequent iterations. The following snippets show that Python's for loop is not (easily) translatable into a while loop, and also shows that with a while loop your mentor's concern is valid:

```
>>> def find_number_of_iterations():
    print("called")
    return 3

>>> for i in range(find_number_of_iterations()): print(i)

called
0
1
2

>>> i = 0
>>> while i < find_number_of_iterations():
    print(i)
    i += 1


called
0
called
1
called
2
called
```

Answer (score 1):

Either way, the function only gets called once. You can demonstrate this as follows:

```
>>> def test_func():
    """Function to count calls and return integers."""
    test_func.called += 1
    return 3

# first version
>>> test_func.called = 0
>>> x = test_func()
>>> for _ in range(x):
    print 'loop'


loop
loop
loop
>>> test_func.called
1

# second version
>>> test_func.called = 0
>>> 
>>> for _ in range(test_func()):
    print 'loop'


loop
loop
loop
>>> test_func.called
1
```

The function is called once, and *the result of calling that function* is passed to `range` (then the result of calling `range` is iterated over); the two versions are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The function is called once. Logically, were it to be called on every iteration then the loop range could change causing all kinds of havoc. This is easily tested:

```
def find_iterations():
    print "find_iterations called"
    return 5

for n in range(find_iterations()):
    print n
```

Results in:

```
$ python test.py
find_iterations called
0
1
2
3
4
```